# Php session variables, block a user

Tags: php

Hey can any one look over my code and help me... I using apache and I am trying to make it were if the user types in the password and user name incorrectly 3 times it will just forward them to the 404 html page. Unfortunately I am getting some of my code displayed in my browser and im not sure why. I'm knew to php so if the code is sloppy or incorrect please dont hound me about it.

**login.php:**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['wrong']=0;
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if($user == "school"
&& $pass == "homework")
{
echo"Password system work!";
}else{
$_SESSION['wrong']=$_SESSION['wrong']+1;
header( 'Location: http://localhost' ) ;
}
?>
```

**Index.html:**

```
<? session_start(); 
include 'login.php';
global $_SESSION['wrong'];
if($_SESSION['wrong']>=3){
header( 'Location: 404_File_Not_Found.html' ) ; //This is what the browser is showing

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#form{
width:  340px;
height: 400px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
position: relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px;
border: solid 1px #ddd;
padding: 30px 30px 60px 30px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
}
p{
font-family: Verdana;

}
div{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:5%;

}
img{
width: 120;
height: 133;
left: 100px;
position: relative;
}
input{
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:5%;
font-size: 14px;
width: 264px;
padding: 9px 7px 7px;
background: none !important;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;

}
.button:hover{
color: red;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="form">     
<img src="http://traceybaptiste.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/homework2.jpg" />
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <p>User:</p> <input type="text" name="user"></input>
    <p>Pass:</p> <input type="password" name="pass"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button"></input>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**404.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{
background-color:grey;
}
body{
background-image:url("404.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `index.html` won't be parsed as PHP by Apache.  Rename it to `index.php`.

Comment: And get into the habit of calling `exit()` immediately after `header("Location...")`

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure but I think you shouldn't include login.php (second line of index.html). I am kinda new to php too but it seems like your form is on index.html, then you post the data to login.php and you redirect the user from there. It doesnt really make sense to me that you include your login.php  at the start of your form. I might be mistaken but just trying to help.

I also think the code William N wrote is wrong too, thats why you are stuck in login.php, it doesnt redirect you to the localhost if your password is wrong.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['wrong']=0;
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if($user == "school"
&& $pass == "homework")
{
echo"Password system work!";
}else{  
$_SESSION['wrong']=$_SESSION['wrong']+1;
header( 'Location: http://localhost' ) ;}

if($_SESSION['wrong'] == 3)

header( 'Location: diepage.html' ) ;

?>
```

try this.

Edit : Oh, it also seems that you make your $_SESSION['wrong'] reset by assigning 0 to it everytime you load the login.php ($_SESSION['wrong']=0;), so its never going to get to 3. Maybe you can do something like :

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['wrong'])){
$_SESSION['wrong']=0;}
```

So that you would initiate and make it zero only if it didn't get set earlier. But again I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <?php 
> session_start(); 
> $_SESSION['wrong']=0;
> $user = $_POST['user'];
> $pass = $_POST['pass'];
> if($user == "school"
> && $pass == "homework")
> {
> echo"Password system work!";
> }else{  $_SESSION['wrong']=$_SESSION['wrong']+1; if($_SESSION['wrong'] == 3)
>
> header( 'Location: diepage.html' ) ;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: I applied you code, and when I enter the incorrect data i get forwarded to the login, but I stay there. I want it to go back to the login page (localhost.. also called index.html) until it hits 3, then get forwarded to the 404, finally sense the number is 3+ they cannot go back to the index.html file to try and log in. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you file is named `index.html`, it won't be parsed by PHP.

Also, use `<?php` instead of just `<?`, it's more reliable since it doesn't depend on a specific configuration setting.

Comment: Thank you both, I will start using <?php for now on. So your telling me that php wont read the index.html file therefore I should rename that file?

Comment: Exactly. Call it `index.php`

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I renamed the file now, yet when i get forwarded to the login.php it stays there, it doesnt navigate me back to the localhost.